# Can Installer build with Install4j version 6.0.4 support Windows 8.x

Tags: install4j

Could someone tell me if the Installer build with Install4j 6.0.4v support the Windows 8.x?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows 8 and Windows 10 are supported by install4j 6.x.